# Object has no attribute?

Tags: python

I am getting an attribute error, but I cannot figure out why even after looking at multiple previous posts.

```
import math
import time
import random
import os, sys
import os.path as osp
from itertools import chain
from shutil import copy
import copy as cp
from tqdm import tqdm
import pdb

import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import scipy.sparse as ssp
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn import BCEWithLogitsLoss
from torch.nn import ModuleList, Linear, Conv1d, MaxPool1d, Embedding
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

from torch_sparse import coalesce
from torch_scatter import scatter_min
import torch_geometric.transforms as T
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv, SAGEConv, global_sort_pool, global_add_pool
from torch_geometric.data import Data, Dataset, InMemoryDataset, DataLoader
from torch_geometric.utils import (negative_sampling, add_self_loops,
                                   train_test_split_edges, to_networkx, 
                                   to_scipy_sparse_matrix, to_undirected)

import warnings
from scipy.sparse import SparseEfficiencyWarning
warnings.simplefilter('ignore',SparseEfficiencyWarning)

from enclosing_subgraph import *

class WLDynamicDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root, data, split_edge, num_hops, percent=100, split='train', 
                 use_coalesce=False, node_label='drnl', ratio_per_hop=1.0, 
                 max_nodes_per_hop=None, **kwargs):
        self.data = data
        self.split_edge = split_edge
        self.num_hops = num_hops
        self.percent = percent
        self.use_coalesce = use_coalesce
        self.node_label = node_label
        self.ratio_per_hop = ratio_per_hop
        self.max_nodes_per_hop = max_nodes_per_hop
        super(WLDynamicDataset, self).__init__(root)

        pos_edge, neg_edge = get_pos_neg_edges(split, self.split_edge, 
                                               self.data.edge_index, 
                                               self.data.num_nodes, 
                                               self.percent)
        self.links = torch.cat([pos_edge, neg_edge], 1).t().tolist()
        self.labels = [1] * pos_edge.size(1) + [0] * neg_edge.size(1)
        
        if self.use_coalesce:  # compress mutli-edge into edge with weight
            self.data.edge_index, self.data.edge_weight = coalesce(
                self.data.edge_index, self.data.edge_weight, 
                self.data.num_nodes, self.data.num_nodes)

        if 'edge_weight' in self.data:
            edge_weight = self.data.edge_weight.view(-1)
        else:
            edge_weight = torch.ones(self.data.edge_index.size(1), dtype=int)
        self.A = ssp.csr_matrix(
            (edge_weight, (self.data.edge_index[0], self.data.edge_index[1])), 
            shape=(self.data.num_nodes, self.data.num_nodes)
        )
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.links)

    def process(self):
        for idx in range(len(self.links)):
            src, dst = self.links[idx]

            if self.labels[idx]: status = "pos"
            else: status = "neg"

            tmp = k_hop_subgraph(src, dst, self.num_hops, self.A, status, self.ratio_per_hop, 
                                 self.max_nodes_per_hop, node_features=self.data.x)
            data = construct_pyg_graph(*tmp, self.node_label)

            torch.save(data, osp.join(self.processed_dir, 'data_{}.pt'.format(idx)))

    def get(self, idx):
        data = torch.load(osp.join(self.processed_dir, 'data_{}.pt'.format(idx)))
        return data
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/run.py", line 302, in <module>
    main()
  File "/path/to/run.py", line 79, in main
    max_nodes_per_hop=args.max_nodes_per_hop,
  File "/path/to/DataSet.py", line 106, in __init__
    super(WLDynamicDataset, self).__init__(root)
  File "/n/home01/vym1/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/dataset.py", line 92, in __init__
    self._process()
  File "/n/home01/vym1/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch_geometric/data/dataset.py", line 165, in _process
    self.process()
  File "/path/to/DataSet.py", line 137, in process
    for idx in range(len(self.links)):
AttributeError: 'WLDynamicDataset' object has no attribute 'links'
```

I clearly define it in the initiation with respect to the class (ie. `self.links`). Not sure why it wouldn't show. Does anyone know why?

Update: Added imports and full traceback. `run.py` is the script I run, which calls this script called `DataSet.py`

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: How are you instantiating the object and calling that method? You have to instantiate it before anything in `__init__` will be defined.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR:

Change the name of your `process` method. Or if you override it on purpose, make sure that `self.links` is defined in the `__init__` before the call to `super()`.

---

You have overriden a method that is being called inside the `__init__` of `DataSet`. A simplified version of your `__init__` is:

```py
class WLDynamicDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(...):
        ...
        super(WLDynamicDataset, self).__init__(root)

        ...
        self.links = torch.cat([pos_edge, neg_edge], 1).t().tolist()
```

Now from the traceback you have the following stack starting with the `super()` call:

```py
WLDynamicDataset.__init__ --> super(WLDynamicDataset, self).__init__(root) =>
    Dataset.__init__ --> self._process() =>
       Dataset._process --> self.process() =>
           WLDynamicDataset.process --> self.links
```

And then you reference `self.links` in `process` before it was defined in the `__init__`.